# Unresolved reference: text /Unresolved reference: settext

Tags: android, kotlin

this is the code I don't know how to add set text and get text methods without errors

**Unresolved reference: text /Unresolved reference: settext**

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val egyptianpound="Egyptian Pound"
    private val americandoller="American Doller"
    private val AED="AED"
    private val GBD="GBD"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val convertbtn: Button =findViewById(R.id.button)
        val amountedt :TextInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout3)
        val todropmenu: AutoCompleteTextView =findViewById(R.id.todropmenu)
        val resultedt : TextInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.result_edit_text)
        val listofcountry= listOf(egyptianpound , americandoller ,AED , GBD)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.drop_down_list,listofcountry)
        todropmenu.setAdapter(adapter)
        convertbtn.setOnClickListener{
            val amount = amountedt.text.toString().toDouble()
            val result =amount.times(30.95)
           resultedt.settext(result.toString())

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextInputLayout` is just a `ViewGroup` which contains views inside it. The text itself is in `EditText`, which is inside `TextInputLayout`. To get the text you need to get the reference to `EditText`:

```
resultedt.editText?.setText(result.toString())
```

or

```
resultedt.editText?.getText()
```